# append list elements into nested list using list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a list with years  `[1745,1742,1743,1730,1739]` and another nested list 
`[['Bassett', 'Richard', '1745-04-02', 'M', 'sen', 'DE', 'Anti-Administration']]`

I am trying to append the first list year values into the last place of the nested list using **list comprehension**.

```
required output: 
[['Bassett', 'Richard', '1745-04-02', 'M', 'sen', 'DE', 'Anti-Administration', 1745], 
 ['Bland', 'Theodorick', '1742-03-21', 'M', 'rep', 'VA', 'Pro-Administration', 1742]]
```

I tried but I couldn't figure it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zip` to pair the two lists:

```
y = [1745,1742,1743,1730,1739]
l = [['Bassett', 'Richard', '1745-04-02', 'M', 'sen', 'DE', 'Anti-Administration'],
 ['Bland', 'Theodorick', '1742-03-21', 'M', 'rep', 'VA', 'Pro-Administration']]
print([s + [n] for s, n in zip(l, y)])
```

This outputs:

```
[['Bassett', 'Richard', '1745-04-02', 'M', 'sen', 'DE', 'Anti-Administration', 1745], ['Bland', 'Theodorick', '1742-03-21', 'M', 'rep', 'VA', 'Pro-Administration', 1742]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension creates a *new* list. If you want to mutate an existing list, use `list.append()`:

```
lst1 = [1745,1742,1743,1730,1739]
lst2 = [['Bassett', 'Richard', '1745-04-02', 'M', 'sen', 'DE',
         'Anti-Administration'],
        ['Bland', 'Theodorick', '1742-03-21', 'M', 'rep', 'VA',
         'Pro-Administration']]
for year, data in zip(lst1, lst2):
    data.append(year)
```